# Understanding Organization of the CRAM bits in bitstream .bin file

Tags: yosys, ice40

For an iCE40 1k device, Following is the snippet from the output of the command "**iceunpack -vv example.bin**"
I could not understand why there are 332x144 bits?
My understanding is that [1], the CRAM BLOCK[0] starts at the logic tile (1,1), and it should contain:

- 48 logic tiles, each 54x16,
- 14 IO tiles, each 18x16

How the "332  x 144" is calculated?

Where does the IO tile and logic tiles bits are mapped in CRAM BLOCK[0] bits?

e.g., *which bits of CRAM BLOCK[0] indicates the bits for logic tile (1,1) and bits for IO tile (0,1)?*

```
Set bank to 0.
Next command at offset 26: 0x01 0x01
CRAM Data [0]: 332 x 144 bits = 47808 bits = 5976 bytes
Next command at offset 6006: 0x11 0x01
```

[1]. http://www.clifford.at/icestorm/format.html

Thanks.

Comment: The checkerboard pattern should hopefully explain it a bit. And don't forget there is BRAM in there too, which is only 42 wide.

Comment: @DavidShah, that is what i could not understand. height=9x16=144 (OK)
But, Width=6x54+18=324 (which is different here i.e.332) How?

Comment: Looking at that diagram, I think there is just a bit of a gap in the middle

Comment: Yes, I guess, this gap belongs to BRAM[0] to [3]. How Width of 332 is calculated? I can't understand. In this width there are 1 I/O tile and 6 logic tiles, it should be Width=6x54+18=342.

Comment: @DavidShah 324 in the 2nd comment is a Typo. It is 342.

Comment: The BRAM is only 42 wide so the correct calculation is 18+42+5x54 = 330

Comment: I don't know why it is rounded up to 332 resulting in a small gap. Possibly because 332 was an easier number to work with for some internal reason.

Comment: Thanks @DavidShah. Then in the same file what is meant by "BRAM Data [0]: 64 x 128 bits" BRAM Data[] is not mapping to RAMB/RAMT bits?
The snippet from file is: 

`Setting bank offset to 0.

Next command at offset 23963: 0x01 0x03

BRAM Data [0]: 64 x 128 bits = 8192 bits = 1024 bytes`

Comment: That's BRAM initialisation, wrt the 42 bits I'm talking about BRAM routing/mode config

Comment: @DavidShah thanks alot. http://www.clifford.at/icestorm/format.html says that there is "two zero bytes" to each CRAM while Writing SRAM content. That is why it 330+2=332. I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**height**=9x16=144 (1 I/O tile and 8 Logic tiles)

**Width**=18+42+5x54 = 330 (1 I/O tile, 1 ram tile and 5 Logic tiles) plus "two zero bytes" = 332.